# Setup GWT and eclipse on windows

Tags: eclipse, gwt, ide, release

I am looking to build a website in GWT top replace a couple of desktop apps we have here at work, I programmed in java 12 years ago so the code should not be a problem.

I am having problems with installation GET and Eclipse.
I seem that when you use the latest version of Eclipse (Juno 4.2) and try to use the GWt Plug in the installer process fail looking for very specific versions of libaries.

My question is "Is there a recommended version of eclipse and GWT that is not on the cutting edge and I can get to work with relative ease"

Comment: Juno works well with the GWT plugin. Please edit your question to include the errors your are experiencing

Answer (score 1):

I hope [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/GWT/article.html) will help you for using GWT in Eclipse

Comment: TRied this but when adding to the old version I get 'Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.v201208080120-rel-r37)'

Comment: what do you mean by "old version"

Comment: I installed eclipse 3.7 but have now reverte to 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started). Get the newest Eclipse "Juno" and choose the standard java version.
Now you need to use the proper link for the plug in. For Juno it is 4.2. If the guide in the link doesn't work, check your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem I used the standard and java versions of eclipse.. if you using the J2EE version everything runs as normal